# How to preload files blueimp jquery-file-upload angular version?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

When trying to load files previously uploaded from the server the following error is produced.

```
// Load existing files:
$.ajax({
    url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
    dataType: 'json',
    context: $('#fileupload')[0]
}).done(function (result) {
    $(this).fileupload('option', 'done').call(this, $.Event('done'), {result: files});
});

//Exception
jquery.fileupload-angular.js:130 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$apply' of undefined
    at done (jquery.fileupload-angular.js:130)
    at <anonymous>:2:47
```

The following snippet is in the `FileUploadController` which puts the `$scope` into the file data.

```
$element.fileupload(angular.extend(
  {scope: $scope},
  fileUpload.defaults
)).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
    data.scope = $scope;
```

Answer (score 1):

So a solution *"hacky"* was to inject a service into the controller for the directive and call the `generateFileObject(files)` method.

```
.directive('ngUploadForm', [function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'templates/uploadform.html',
    scope: {
      allowed: '@',
      url: '@',
      autoUpload: '@',
      sizeLimit: '@',
      ngModel: '=',
      name: '@'
    },
    controller: ['$scope', '$element', 'fileUpload','FileService', function ($scope, $element, fileUpload, FileService)

[other code]

// pre-populate file list
FileService.getSavedFiles()
  .done(function(files){
    generateFileObject(files)
  });
```

FileService Code (basic jquery ajax)

```
this.getSavedFiles = function(){
    return $.ajax({
      url: this.getFileUrl(),
      dataType: 'json'
    });
```